# Creating folders by checking numbers at beginning of a string with python

Tags: python, directory

I have a list of strings which contains files like below

```
filename = [ '000101 FL - Project Title Page.DOC',
 '014200 FL - References.DOC',
 '095446 FL - Fabric-Wrapped Ceiling Panels.DOC',
 '142113 FL - ELECTRIC TRACTION FREIGHT ELEVATORS.DOC']
```

I want to check if a folder with a name consisting of Div + first two numbers in each string exist, such as Div00, Div01, Div09, Div14 in this case. If not I would like to create this folder. Then store the name of the file in this folder.

In pseudocode I believe it would be similar to

```
for file in filenames 
    if 'Div' + file[0][0] not a folder
        make folder 'Div' + file[0][0]
        add file to folder
    else
        add file to folder Div + file[0][0]
```

There will be multiple files starting with the same two numbers this is why I want to sort them into folder.

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Do you want to copy the file to the folder, move the file to the folder, or create an empty file with the file name in the folder?

Comment: @DavidCullen I should have clarified that. I want to copy all the files beginning with XX to a new folder titled DivXX

Comment: @Jstuff, copy or move?

Comment: @sparkandshine, I would rather copy them. That way if something goes wrong the original files still exist or I can easily go back to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) to create a directory and [`shutil.copy2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) to copy a file,

```
import os
import shutil

filenames = [ '000101 FL - Project Title Page.DOC']

for filename in filenames:
    folder = 'Div' + filename[:2]       # 'Div00'

    # Create the folder if doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)

    # Copy the file to `folder`
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        shutil.copy2(filename, folder)  # metadata is copied as well
```

Comment: Div is is not initially present in the filenames. It needs to be added later.

Comment: @Jstuff, sorry for misinterpretion. Just edited my answer.

Comment: Alright I get the error. PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\justin.white\\Desktop\\Master_specs_With_Divisions\\Div00' When trying to copy the file to the new folder. Never mind didn't realize I needed to use copy2.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, what is the reason to replace `''.join(['Div', filename[:2]])` with `'Div' + filename[:2]`.

Comment: @sparkandshine: Sorry, it was just a minor tweak. Using `join` doesn't save you anything here, and makes the code a little less clear (and slower, since it's now creating/discarding a temp`list`, then calling `join` to perform the concatenation that `+` does directly without extra temporaries). `join` is good when concatenating an existing sequence of `str`, or concatenating many `str`, but for two `str`, it saves nothing and distracts from the rest of the code which is illustrating something more complicated than string concatenation. Sorry if you felt it was frivolous.

Comment: @sparkandshine it works using shutil.copy2, but after all the folders are created and the files are copied. I get an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0'. I could just tell the script to ignore the error and continue, but I would rather know why it is happening and fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jstuff, this error is raised by your input `filenames`. Add the condition `if os.path.isfile(filename)` before copy. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if there is a folder and make it if it does not exist

```
if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.makedirs(dirName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import os
import shutil

for file in filenames
    dir_name = "Div%s" % file[0:2]
    if not os.path.isdir(dir_name)
        os.makedirs(dir_name)
    shutil.copy(file, dir_name)
```